# PulseIn tachometer

Tags: pulsein

I tried to create a tachometer for my motorcycle using an Arduino Uno.
I am trying to measure the voltage of the ignition coil (stepped down to not destroy the Arduino).

I am trying to determine the time between two explosions (one ignition coil high voltage).

I tried to use the `pulseIn` command in the following way:

```cpp
unsigned pin=8;
float t;

unsigned long rpm;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    rpm=pulseIn(pin,LOW);

    Serial.println(rpm/60);
}
```

The problem with it is that it won't display stable values. It will go all crazy.
With an open circuit it still displays random values.

Comment: Are you sure that pulse is not shorter than 10ms?

Comment: i tested both pulseIn(pin,LOW) and pulseIn(pin,high) and neither worked. At most, my bike does 14.000 rpm, meaning 14.000/60 (233) rps.
233 rps ..... 1000 ms
x rps............1 ms
x=233/1000.
I guess it is less than 10 ms.
Is that the problem?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/pulseIn - under 10ms it wont work right

Comment: but if you have tested it with smaller speed, the problem will be somewhere else

Comment: I am curious, how do you get to incorporate ignition coil into your circuit?

Comment: I suspect that it is already too late for that Arduino. How are you safely stepping the voltage down in such a way that it doesn't a) kill the Arduino, and b) kill you?

Comment: btw: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/318/how-precise-is-the-timing-of-pulsein?rq=1

Comment: pulseIn works for values less than 10ms, it returns time in 'micro Seconds'. Try        Serial.println(pulseIn(pin,LOW));

Comment: I did not use the high voltage terminal. I took the minus from the coil primary minus (the 12v terminal) and the plus from the battery, since the ground is the one that continuously varies in an ignition coil. I used a voltage divider to step the voltage down to acceptable levels.

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned that there is back EMF from primary coil when switch (or points) becomes open. This means that there is 200-300V applied backwards to your voltage divider while you think there is only 0-12V.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why that isn't working, but I can give you a working alternative.

```
unsigned int pin=8;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    unsigned float rpm = 0;

    while (digitalRead(pin) == FALSE) {
        rpm++;
        delayMicroseconds(1);
    }

    Serial.println(rpm/60);
}
```

I might've forgotten something, but that should work.

Edit: the comments may be right, are you stepping down your input voltage?